# Soft delete and restore associative table record

Tags: sql, database

Let's say we have three tables **Person**, **Group** and **PersonGroup**.
The key in **PersonGroup** is composite(PersonId and GroupId). There's an extra column in - DeletedOn, which is used for soft deletion of a specific record(person is removed from group).

I wоnder how can be restored the specific record in **PersonGroup**?

The first, probably the easiest one is just to remove date stamp from deleted on.

Another one is to create new record for the specific combination but then I would violate unique constraint of the composite key.
How the second option can be done?

Thanks!
Guero

Comment: Set `deletedOn to `NULL` or `0`.  That undeletes the record.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!
Is it possible somehow to keep the record which was previously flagged with DeletedOn date and to create new record for the same combination?

Comment: Not if you have a unique index/constraint on just the two columns.  You should really ask a new question, with sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want to do, and the database you are using.

Comment: If you need to save deletion/restoration history, then you need another table for this - either some generic log table or specific one for single purpose. Or in newer MS SQL versions (and likely in other DBMS) you may have temporal tables, which retain changes history over time.